# Find index where column value is matched in other column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe with two integer columns like:

```
   a  b
0  5  7
1  3  5
2  7  1
```

I need an additional column containing the index where the value of column `a` equals that of column `b` of the current row.  I. e.: `b=7` is matched by `a=7` at index `2`, `b=5` by `a=5` at index `0`, `b=1` is not matched. Desired output:

```
   a  b  c
0  5  7  2
1  3  5  0
2  7  1  NaN
```

There will never be multiple lines where the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Could there be duplicates in column `a` ?

Comment: @Psidom There are duplicates in `a` but those values wont be in `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option with [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
# sort column a and find candidate position of values in b in a
df.sort_values('a', inplace=True)
pos = df.a.searchsorted(df.b)

# handle edge case when the pos is out of bound
pos[pos == len(pos)] = len(pos) - 1

# assign the index to column as c and mark values that don't match as nan
df['c'] = df.index[pos]
df.loc[df.a.loc[df.c].values != df.b.values, 'c'] = np.nan

df.sort_index()

#   a  b    c
#0  5  7  2.0
#1  3  5  0.0
#2  7  1  NaN
```